# A question about the famous bucket experiment

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

Suppose that we have a bucket containing two liquids with different densities.Suppose also that i connect the bucket with an electric motor and i rotate the bucket.

1. Why when the bucket rotates, the heavier liquid is pushed to the outer periphery?
2. Have i contrived a machine that produces gravity? This is the impression that i have after a google research. Could someone give an intuitive explanation about how is gravity involved?

**EDIT
What is pulling the liquid outside? Is it the all the astronomical matter as Mach wrote? How is it attracted to the walls of the bucket?**
EDIT NO2

Although the question is tagged newtonian mechanics i think it rather belongs, as the answers suggest, to general relativity. I would really appreciate an intuitive or not answer at the context of general relativity

Comment: This is inertia, not gravity.

Comment: @rob Renowned Walter Lewin says that it is gravity.

Comment: I think you are confusing this with simulated gravity that is seen in many science fiction stories, in which a space station contains a large rotating section such that the centrifugal force simulates a gravitational field allowing people to live under "normal" conditions.  It would, in fact, produce such an effect, but it is not the gravitational force.

Comment: @tmwilson26 The argument of Lewin. If i hang a book with a string from the ceiling the tension of the string keeps the book up and gravity pulls down. If i rotate 90 degrees, then again is tension and gravity

Comment: There's a profound connection between inertia and gravity which is too complex for this comment box.

Comment: @rob You could write an answer instead

Comment: @veronica - could you please link to the site (probably one of his online lectures) where you think he said that? I'm certain that you got it wrong.  It's not gravity, and Lewin didn't say it was.

Comment: @ WhatRoughBeast If i remember well he said that on his lecture on circular  motion and he explains nothing more probably in agreement with @rob that  it is a profound issue

Comment: @ WhatRoughBeast Regardless Mr Lewin opinion, could you tell me why it doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: @veronica - One more time, "could you please link to the site (probably one of his online lectures) where you think he said that?"  If you can't, then say so. I suspect that you are referring to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWj1ZEQTI8I "Circular Motion, Centrifugal Forces, Perceived Gravity " Notice that he talks about "PERCEIVED gravity", not real gravity.

Comment: –@ WhatRoughBeastIt is this and he finishes his argument without mentioning the word perceived. Moreover he adds nothing to make things clear. Maybe a silly question. If gravity is a fictitious force or a pseudoforce or a result of spacetime geometry what is the difference between real and perceived? For me, it is a riddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **What is pulling the liquid outside?**

Nothing.

What is happening is that the bucket is pulling the liquid *inwards* towards its centre of rotation. This means the liquid does not continue travelling in a straight line, which it would do in the absence of any force acting on it.

---

> **Have I invented artificial gravity?**

Not really.

Einstein [observed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) that the water in the bucket is unable to distinguish between the two situations

- It is sitting in a bucket on a planet whose gravity pulls the water towards the base of the bucket.
- It is sitting in a bucket that is a non-inertial reference frame, i.e. is being accellerated (in this example by a centripetal force).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i suspect that there is something more than this

Comment: @veronika: Why do you suspect that?

Comment: The link that you suggested helped me understand my own question.I do not understand why the gravitational force experienced by all of us standing on planet earth is actually the same by the force experienced by water as it separates from fuel in the centrifugal separator of a merchant vessel?

Comment: I suggest you rephrase your Q and ask about the equivalence principle. You might want to use a different example. E.g. A man in a windowless spaceship a) stationary on the launchpad on a nonrotating Earth-like interstellar planet at sea-level. b) alone in interstellar space accellerating at $9.8 ms^{-2}$

Comment: I will follow your advice, i used the centrifuge example it seemed to me more clear

Answer (score 1):

1) As the bucket spins, frictional forces will gradually spin up the liquids until their rotational rate matches the bucket. Let's say that the radius of the bucket is R, and the rotational rate of the bucket is $\omega $ Then, for liquid near the wall of the bucket, a small volume of the liquid with mass M will feel an apparent radial force outward of $$F =M \frac{\omega ^2}{R} $$ This is simply centrifugal force, and there is no need to go into questions of whether it's a "real" force or not.

So, for two liquids with different densities (that is, the liquids have different densities, which is not necessarily the same as your statement the one liquid is heavier than the other), the denser liquid will be driven outward harder than the lighter liquid, and this will cause the denser liquid to migrate outward. To switch gears a bit, it's the same reason a dense object sinks in water. The dense object is pulled down by gravity more than the volume of water which it displaces.

2) Have you invented a gravity machine? Well, yes and no. No in the sense that you have not actually produced gravity, which acts on an object regardless of its motion.

But yes in the sense that you have found a way to produce a force which behaves very much like gravity AS LONG AS THE MOTION OF THE BODIES INVOLVED ARE FORCED TO MOVE IN A CERTAIN WAY. Actually, what you've "invented" is a centrifuge. These are widely used in medicine to separate blood and other liquids into their component parts for analysis. On a large scale, like hundreds of feet across, such a device could be used to provide "artificial gravity" for people in space. A large enough centrifuge spinning fast enough (but not fast enough for the inner ear to detect the rotation and make folks dizzy and maybe seasick) could provide an environment in space which would prevent the bad effects of zero-g.

EDIT - With the addition of the question,

> **"What is pulling the liquid outside? Is it the all the astronomical**
>   **matter as Mach wrote? How is it attracted to the walls of the bucket?"**

I'll expand my answer. You are, I think, referring to Lewin's online lecture [Circular Motion, Centrifugal Forces, Perceived Gravity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWj1ZEQTI8I)  and he specifically discusses your question at about 17 minutes into the lecture. At about 22:30, he talks about "creating artificial gravity". But he then discusses the situation ALWAYS in terms of "what do you feel", rather than "what is the direction of gravity", and you need to pay attention to the difference. He then talks about centrifuges at about 35 minutes in. His explanation is clearer than I can hope for, but I'll try to rephrase it.

Consider an atom at the end of a string, which is being spun around a central point. At some time, cut the string. What will happen to the atom? It will fly off in a straight line which is perpendicular to the string at the moment it was cut. So that is how an atom (or any mass) in the absence of an external force. "Things in motion tend to stay in motion." Now think about the atom when the string is not cut. In order to remain in circular motion, a force along the line of the string must be constantly applied. If it weren't, the atom would move in a straight line, not a circle. It is this force which you are referring to as an attraction, and it isn't.

Please watch the lecture again, and pay attention to the fact that he is talking about perceived gravity.

Comment: Yes, it is a centrifuge but half a centrifuge. What i must add to make it work is a perforated disk stack to oppose the coriolis force and a centripetal pump for each of the separated liquids. Thank you for your answer. What i ask is what pulling the liquid outside? I will edit the question

Comment: What is pulling the liquid outside is its inertia. The liquid tries to keep going straight on a tangential path, but the outer surface has to keep pushing on it to keep the liquid in the bucket. From the point of view of the liquid, the liquid is pushing on the wall  of the bucket.

Comment: I will make a concession and i will admit that he uses the word perceived although he does not. But after the word gravity what follows is silence...Is there an intricate relation between what you describe as inertia and gravity?  What is the difference between real and perceived gravity? Once more i want to thank you for your long answer

Comment: @veronica - "Real" gravity is the force produced by the existence of any two masses. "Perceived" gravity is the magnitude of the force measured by an object which is not due to things like electric charge.  At the level of knowledge we're talking about here, there is no connection between inertia and gravity. When you get to studying General Relativity that will change, but for now, forget about it.

Comment: My question was all about general relativity and i will not forget about it (lol )

Comment: @veronica - Well, I'll keep that in mind. However, do you understand that the liquid is not attracted to the walls of the bucket? Another way of looking at is the the liquid tries to keep moving in a straight line, and the bucket keeps getting in the way. It's like running into a wall because you forgot to turn - that doesn't say the wall attracted you.

Comment: What you mention nobody can deny.It is absolutely true.But your answer and the answer of RedGrittyBrick reluctantly point to the direction of the equivalence theorem which i believe is more rich in meaning.

Comment: @veronica - Equivalence principle doesn't hold for rotating frames of reference. "simulated gravity" produced by a centrifuge is easily distinguished from the real thing. And you haven't answered the question: do you understand that  the liquid is not attracted to the bucket walls?

Comment: Why the equivalence principle doesn't hold for rotating frames of reference?

Comment: Because, as I stated, " 'simulated gravity' produced by a centrifuge is easily distinguished from the real thing." Gravity does not exhibit Coriolus forces. And for the 3rd time, "do you understand that the liquid is not attracted to the bucket walls? "